# Pytest command line argument for @pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to find command line arguments in pytest with distributed test execution?

```
py.test -n 16  tests/tests_*****.py --env="TestEnvironemnt" --html=XYZ/Reports.html
```

os.sys.argv is giving as '-c' in my code , if am executing my pytest code

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but does [this example](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options) answer it?

Comment: Link above is not working for me. The following is, however: http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear but I assume you want to add an option "--env" and read its value.

The way to do it is:

1. Create a file **conftest.py** in your project (if it does not exist yet) and add the option *--env*

---

```
#conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--env', action="store", dest="env", default="",
    help="Define name of test environment")
```

---

2. [optional] Assign a fixture **env_name** with the value of option *--env*

---

```
#conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def env_name(request):
    return request.config.getoption('env')
```

---

3. In your test function, use the fixture *env_name*, which which you can get the value of the option.
   If not defined, use fixture *request* instead and get the value with `request.config.getoption('env')`

---

```
#test.py
def test1(env_name):
    print("Test Environment is: {}".format(env_name))
```